# Cap.findDevice return all time undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, winpcap, npcap

I try to work on packet with cap but is not work.
I have try the default code :

```
const Cap = __cap.Cap
const decoders = __cap.decoders
const PROTOCOL = decoders.PROTOCOL

var c = new Cap();
var device = Cap.findDevice('192.168.0.10');
var filter = 'tcp and dst port 80';
var bufSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
var buffer = Buffer.alloc(65535);

console.log(device);
```

But every time Cap.findDevice return **undefine**.
I have install npcap with WinPcap compatibility.
I have try to a lot of different ip but no one work.

Some one have an answer ?

Thank in advance. Have a good day.

Comment: Well have you checked what your device's IP is?

Comment: I was thinking it's the remote ip not mine. Thanks so mutch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that's my bad i dont understand the ip is for the listening interface , i was think is the remote ip. So i have put my ip and is work.